# Google Play balance expiration date format

Tags: google-play-store

I have a Google play balance of 30 eur, which is said to expire on `9/1/2023`. My preferred language on Google account is set to English (United States), but my real-life region is in Europe, and uses a date format of `D/M/YYYY`.
[image: Google play balance]

How can I be sure which date format is used for the expiration date above, i.e., will it expire tomorrow (9th of January) or in several months (1st of September)?

Note that the gift card was redeemed around 1st of September 2022. (not sure the exact date, but it is possible that it is indeed the 1st), so if the expiration date was 1 year exactly, it would make sense that the date format above is `M/D/YYYY`

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but there may be `hl` and `gl` parameters on the URL. `hl` is for page language (including date format) and `gl` is for geolocation (including currency format). Changing their values may help to disambiguate.

Comment: [How to add to and check your Google Play balance](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/3423011?hl=en-GB&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop) has one of those params, but the Check your Play balance link doesn't: [https://play.google.com/store/paymentmethods?pli=1](https://play.google.com/store/paymentmethods?pli=1). I also tried looking through some requests in dev tools, but they seem too hard to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note that the gift card was redeemed around 1st of September 2022. (not sure the exact date, but it is possible that it is indeed the 1st), so if the expiration date was 1 year exactly, it would make sense that the date format above is M/D/YYYY

Gift cards don't expire as stated on [Google Play Gift Card® And Prepaid Play Balance Terms Of Service](https://support.google.com/googleplay/thread/8323313/how-do-i-check-when-my-google-play-credits-expire-and-if-they-expire-at-all?hl=en#:%7E:text=3.%20No%20Fees%20or%20Expiration.%20No%20fees%20or%20expiration%20dates%20apply%20to%20this%20Gift%20Card%20or%20Credit.)

> 3. No Fees or Expiration. No fees or expiration dates apply to this Gift Card or Credit.

However, opinion rewards do expire as stated on [Redeem rewards](https://support.google.com/consumersurveys/answer/6322284?hl=en#:%7E:text=Do-,my%20credits,-expire%3F):

> Do my credits expire?
>
> Yes. Google Play credits received expire one year from date of credit per the Google Opinion Rewards Terms of Service

Based on what you said about gift card in September, I am assuming that it wasn't normal gift card but opinion rewards that you collect back in then. If I am correct, then the date is September, not January. Also the fact that the `9` is single digit instead of double, make me think that it is the month (not the date) in the `M/D/yyyy` or `M/DD/yyyy` formats. If I am wrong, only a few hours left and I will have to delete this answer (and your balance goes).

Comment: It was indeed a special "gift card". Got it from a Samsung stand on a festival. I managed to find a good use of those 30, with only 0.03€ left, so we'll see if it's removed within a day. If not, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @PajLe Let wait until California officially reaches 09 January 2023 :)